# Cypress does not recognize list element

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cypress

I am trying to run Cypress tests for a Angular based Frontend.
In this application there is a list-component that includes several message-list-items. The problem I'm currently facing is that Cypress does not recognize all message-list-items displayed.I want to compare the expected number of messages with the actual number of displayed messages. At the moment I do not understand Cypress's behavior. Sometimes Cypress recognizes all message-list-items and sometimes a single message is skipped (totally random which one). In the HTML  the message-list-item exists and I can see the message-list-item beeing rendered too. Cypress just does not highlight or recognize it at all.

Here is a screenshot of the message-list-item in the HTML
[HTML message-list-items available](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ziQeW.png)

A screenshot from Cypress logs [Cypress log output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iJDvc.png)

The code to acess the message-list-items:

```
 cy.wait(2000).then(() =>
      cy.get('message-list')
        .each(($el, index) => {
          cy.wrap($el).then(() => (resultCounter += 1));
        })
        .then(() =>
          expect(resultCounter).equals(
            expectedMessageCounter
          )
        )
    );
```

Anyone faced the same problem? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to do this without any flaky results is

```js
cy.get('message-list-item')
  .should('have.length', expectedMessageCounter)
```

Because you have a `.should()`, Cypress will retry up to 4 seconds for the correct length.

You do not need to `.each()`.